# What do capture-the-flag challenges involve?

Tags: cracking

What are capture the flag challenges?

What exactly do they involve? I know they are hacking challenges, but what form does the 'flag' take? How do you know if you've won?

Comment: Close this question, as it is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the flag involves using various commands usually in linux and windows to navigate file directories for some challenges. When you enter a challenge you will usually have a certain amount of time to find as many flags as you can. Each flag is worth a different amount of points usually based on difficulty. There will usually be a prompt through the online competition that will give you hints as to what to look for. Flags could be file names or parts of files that need to be found using certain commands. Some are obvious like what is the ip address of the computer? - this would also award a smaller amount of points than a cryptography question like crack this encryption    AIPSEHFPASF923r02yua (not real encrypted text just an example). To earn points you would submit the "flag" into your teams online account next to the prompt. To submit the flag like in the first example for an ip address you would simply enter 192.168.x.x or whatever the ip address was.

Some typical categories for capture the flag challenges are:

- Windows command line
- Linux command line
- cryptography
- sql injection
- url navigation to find hidden files

There are obviously more areas they can question you on but these are just some I encountered.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

CTFs are computer security/hacking competitions which generally consist of participants breaking, investigating, reverse engineering and doing anything they can to reach the end goal, a "flag" which is usually found as a string of text.

DEF CON hosts what is the most widely known and first major CTF, occurring annually at the hacking conference in Las Vegas. Many different competitions have branched off since then, and numerous ones are available year round. One of the best places to see when CTFs are being scheduled is CTFTime, an active website with calendars and team rankings.